# <a href> coming before span in css

Tags: html, css

I am creating a jobs page and was just making this when I ran across what I think is a styling problem.

If you look at the image below you can see the Apply button comes before the time and city but I want the Apply button to be farthest to the left but it will not position that way which only led me to believe this is a styling error on my part. Does anybody know why this would be? Code posted below.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="job-case">
    <h4>iOS Engineer</h4>
    <span>Chicago</span>
    <a href="#">Apply</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.job-case {
    height: 0 auto;
    width: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid none;;
}
.job-case:hover {
    background-color: #F3EFF5;
    border-color: #212121;
}
.job-case h4 {
    color: #212121;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.job-case a {
    float: right;
    height: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #72b01d;
    background-color: none;
    border: 2px solid #72b01d;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.job-case a:hover {
    background-color: #72b01d;
    border-color: #72b01d;
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.job-case span {
    float: right;
    padding: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #212121;
}
```

Comment: farther to the left or to the right ?

Comment: I would like the apply button to be furthest to the right

Comment: in `.job-case a` ruleset you have `height: 0 auto;` pick one or the other, although `line-height` would be better. `padding` doesn't have an `auto` value like `margin` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a styling issue. When using `float:right` on siblings they stack and they go to the right in the order they are in the DOM. so the first one with `float:right` will go to the farthest right.

So you need to change the html and put the `a` before the `span`

```
<div class="job-case">
    <h4>iOS Engineer</h4>
    <a href="#">Apply</a>
    <span>Chicago</span>
</div>
```

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/g8kuve66/

---

Quoting the [`float` specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#floats)

> A floated box is shifted to the left **or right until its outer edge touches the containing block edge or the outer edge of another float**. If there is a line box, the outer top of the floated box is aligned with the top of the current line box.